# Rotar N angulo un ImageView respectando el angulo inicial en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

¿Cómo rotar una imagen teniendo en cuenta el angulo que esta actualmente?

Ejemplo al pulsar un botón rote una imagen `180º a 180º`

Es decir

```
click 0º a 180º
click 180º a 360º
click botón 0º...
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución parte en definir dos animaciones de 0 a 180 y de 180 a 360, dependiendo de lo que se necesite se iniciar una animación o otra.

Definición de animaciones en XML

**rotate_0_to_180.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="180" />

</set>
```

**rotate_180_to_360.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="180"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Al hacer click

```
Animation rotation;

if (!sortASC){
    rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate_0_to_180);
} else {
    rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate_180_to_360);
}

rotation.setFillEnabled(true);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);

sortBtnIcon.startAnimation(rotation);
```

#### Editado

Método sin crear animaciones en xml

`private float mCurrRotation = 0.0f;`

**Función rotateViewFromToDegreeAnim**

```
private float rotateViewFromToDegreeAnim(View v, float degreeStart, float degrees, long velocity) {

    RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(degreeStart, degreeStart + degrees,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    degreeStart = (degreeStart + degrees) % 360;

    rotateAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnim.setDuration(velocity);
    rotateAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    v.startAnimation(rotateAnim);

    return degreeStart;
}
```

Su uso es el siguiente
`rotateViewFromToDegreeAnim(image_view,grados_iniciales,grados_a_girar,velocdad)`
 devuelve el total de grados que quedará la imagen después de la rotación.

Para girar 90º a 90º

`mCurrRotation = rotateViewFromToDegreeAnim(sortBtnIcon,mCurrRotation,90,300L);`

Para girar de 180º a 180º

`mCurrRotation = rotateViewFromToDegreeAnim(sortBtnIcon,mCurrRotation,180,300L);`

Answer (score 1):

Hace Mucho Tiempo trabaje con rotar la imagen utilize canvas en android studio puedes visitar el proyecto

https://github.com/cjoseanguiano/RotateBitmap--Android-Studio